# To prove that ${2+i \choose i}\equiv k \mod n$ is not possible that $k=0,1,\ldots,n-1 \forall i\ge 0$ and $i \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $n$ is odd.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

To prove that ${2+i \choose i}\equiv k \mod n$ is not possible that $k=0,1,\ldots,n-1 \forall i\ge 0$ and $i \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $n$ is odd.

This is a problem from ISI 2014 written test in a little varied form. I could not attempt the problem at all. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Don't think the problem makes sense -- the LHS is a positive integer, so must belong to one of the residue classes $\in \{ 0, 1, 2, \dots , n-1 \}$ modulo $n$.

Comment: I think you have to restate the question...

Comment: I think they are asking to show that for at least one $k\in\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$, there is no solution to ${2+i\choose i}\equiv k\pmod n$.

Comment: @Casteels Yes, you have correctly understood the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are asking is to show that if $n$ is odd, then for at least one $k\in\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$, there is no solution to ${2+i\choose i}\equiv k\bmod n$.

Well, ${2+i\choose i}={2+i\choose 2}$ and, since $n$ is odd, ${2+i\choose 2}\equiv {2+i+n\choose 2} \bmod n$. In other words, the sequence $\left({i+2\choose 2}\bmod n\right)_{i=0}^\infty$ is periodic with period $n$. So it's enough to consider the first $n$ terms, i.e., $$S=\left({2\choose 2}\bmod n,{3\choose 2}\bmod n,\ldots, {n+1\choose 2}\bmod n\right).$$ We need to show that there is at least one $k\in\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$ *not* appearing as an entry in $S$.

If $n=3$, $S=(1,0,0)$ and so $k=2$ is the required missing number $k$.

For $n\geq 5$, we have ${2\choose 2}\equiv 1\pmod n$ and ${n-1\choose 2}\equiv 1\bmod n$. Hence $1$ appears twice amongst the $n$ entries in $S$, and so at least one number in $\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$ does *not* appear in $S$.

Comment: I really like your idea, but there are some places where I do not understand, first, how do you get ${2+i \choose 2}\equiv {2+i+n \choose 2} \mod n$?

Comment: Need to use some modular arithmetic facts: (1) Since $2$ and $n$ are coprime, $2^{-1}$ exists; (2) $x\equiv x+n\bmod n$ for all $x$; and (3) if $a\equiv b\bmod n$ and $c\equiv d\bmod n$, then $ab\equiv cd\bmod n$. Putting all of these together we get $2^{-1}(2+i)(1+i)\equiv 2^{-1}(2+i+n)(1+i+n)$, which is ${2+i\choose 2}\equiv {2+i+n\choose 2}\bmod n$.

Comment: @Swadhin By the way, you could also use that ${n+1\choose 2}$ and ${n\choose 2}$ are both $0\bmod n$. Maybe that's more natural. Anyway, let me know about if you have other questions.